# Create a Dynamic SQL View based on database state

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, view

On my MS SQL Server 2008 I have a database table that receives a feed that I do not control from an external data source that is **huge**. This table is used for many production processes. During the feed the entire table is truncated and then repopulated hourly. It only takes about 5-10 seconds for the process, but has caused occasional hiccups to the web based processes using this data.

I have another table that is the same identical structure of the replaced data that reflects the last good snapshot of data from the last successful feed. In an effort to remediate the issue without a ton of acrobatics I wanted to create view that points the the primary table if populated, or shadow/clone table of the last good snapshot if the primary table is not populated.

I have tried two ideas on how to tackle this but I can't get either to work right. Using a Delta Update is not a viable option since it takes longer to update the modified records than the 1 hour to complete the change. This is just suppose to be a band-aid  over the 5 - 10 second window up feed update so all the queries can reference one live abstracted view to take complexity away.

Any ideas on how to tackle this monster?

**Method A**

Using a stored procedure I can easily do this...

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_v_feed
AS
BEGIN
        IF (
                (SELECT COUNT(F.asset_tag) AS records FROM feed F)
                >
                (SELECT COUNT(FS.asset_tag) AS records FROM feed_shadow FS) 
            )  AND (
                (SELECT COUNT(F.asset_tag) AS records FROM feed F) < 80000
            )       
            SELECT * FROM feed_shadow;      
        ELSE
            SELECT * FROM feed;
END
GO
```

but how do I make a view of this? (throws syntax error)

```
CREATE VIEW v_feed AS EXEC sp_v_feed
```

**Method B**

The other route of just making a view doesn't seem to work either:

```
CREATE VIEW v_feed 
    IF (
            (SELECT COUNT(F.id) AS records FROM feed F)
            >
            (SELECT COUNT(FS.id) AS records FROM feed_shadow FS) 
        )  AND (
            (SELECT COUNT(F.id) AS records FROM feed F) < 10000000
        )       
        SELECT * FROM feed_shadow;      
    ELSE
        SELECT * FROM feed;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a table-valued function would get you what you're looking for.

Take a look at Cade Roux's answer to this question:
[TSQL - If..Else statement inside Table-Valued Functions - cant go through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544269/tsql-if-else-statement-inside-table-valued-functions-cant-go-through)

In case you aren't familiar with table-valued functions, you can query a table-valued function just like you can query a view.

Comment: Based on my notes about the table being huge I am worried about performance if I went to a Table valued function. Based on articles from MS, it appears performance degrades quickly when you start getting thousands of rows of data, and this table is close to 500k rows and 3 dozen of columns. Do you have first hand experience with large data sets and TVF's? Is this something I need to consider or do you think it would still be a good solution?